# TV show with dark purple airship, turban-wearing guardian

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

In the late eighties or early nineties, I watched an animated TV show that seemed to be a mix of fantasy and science fiction.  I apologize for this being so vague, but here is what I remember.

- There was a hero, and I think he carried a sword
- There was a princess type, and she and the hero fought.  I think she had some special power
- There was a guy with a turban who I think was the guardian of the princess type.  He could fly by sitting cross legged.
- The bad guy wanted the princess, and in at least one episode, he caught her.  He had this giant airship that I remember being very dark purple or black.

In the episode where the princess is kidnapped, she is being held on the airship.  The hero guy makes the turban guy fly him up to the ship, and it's very awkward because the turban guy can only fly by sitting cross legged.

In my mind, it seems like it might be some anime, but it wasn't subtitled and it played on one of the cheap, little stations in Dallas TX in the late eighties or early nineties on Sunday mornings.

Can anybody help?  Clearly the turban flying guy is fantasy, but I seem to remember at least a little high tech stuff.

Comment: Can't remember it enough to say if all the details match, but maybe Conan the Adventurer?  I know there was a turbaned guy who I believe could fly (also had a brother and sister who were wolves).

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out!  It's the apparently very unpopular Dragon Quest anime, *[Dragon Quest: Legend of the Hero Abel](https://dragonquest.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Quest:_Legend_of_the_Hero_Abel)*!

[image: Title image of Dragon Quest: Legend of the Hero Abel]

> In the Ariahan village, on her 15th birthday, Tiala receives a red jewel from the elder Yogi. The jewel is the key to awaken the Great Dragon, whose blood grants eternal life. Due to this, the demon Baramos kidnaps Tiala. His childhood friend, Abel tries unsuccessfully to save her. He is given a blue jewel, the counterpart of the jewel that Tiala received, that can seal the Great Dragon and embarks on a mission to rescue Tiala.

Comment: Glad you found it. Please accept your answer to mark the questions as answered.